# Why am I getting incorrect layout when using the "Grid" component of 'semantic-ui-react'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, web-applications

I have the following hierarchy in my project

```
project
- node_modules
- public
- src
  - components
    - CustomGrid.js
  - App.js
```

as well as the other standard files in any *React* project: `package.json`, `README`, `package-lock.json`, `.gitignore`.

`CustomGrid.js` contains the following code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Grid } from 'semantic-ui-react';

class CustomGrid extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Grid columns={2}>
        <Grid.Column>
          <p>Hello World</p>
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column>
          <p>Hello World</p>
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomGrid;
```

`App.js` contains the following code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CustomGrid from './components/CustomGrid';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <CustomGrid />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The output I get is as follows

[image]

However, based on my code and the specification [here](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/grid#grid-example-grid), the two 'Hello World' statements should be side-by-side. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the semantic ui css? See https://react.semantic-ui.com/usage#css

Comment: Thanks. And yes, I was missing the CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install semantic css module
`npm i semantic-ui-css`
and then import it to your index.js
`import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";`

You can see the result at this codesandbox: [SemanticGridTest](https://codesandbox.io/s/r53zvr0pvp)

NOTE: this way you import the whole Semantic-css-library.
 It's ok for development but not for production.